# Negative XPath contains() search for Selenium testing

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to get the number of items in my website that contain the class 'ssid-entry' and this results in 8 elements, but I noticed it also included a hidden element.

It grabs this:

```
div class="ssid-entry empty ng-hide" ng-show="privateSsids.length < 1"
```

Not just this:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'ssid-entry')]
```

So, I need an XPath expression that searches for `ssid-entry` but not the ones with empty `ng-hide` in them.
I tried

```
//*[contains(@class, 'ssid-entry') not contains(@class,'empty ng-hide')]
```

which didn't work, but I can't seem to find the answer. I tried several variations of combinations that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`not` in XPath is a function, not an operator. See [its specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-not).

So you need to write this:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'ssid-entry') and
    not(contains(@class,'empty')) and  
    not(contains(@class,'ng-hide'))]
```